# NoMethodError: private method `browser_name' called for {:browserName=>:firefox, :version=>nil}:Hash

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am trying to learn selenium Grid, I followed a tutorial, but when I try to run my feature I got this error :

NoMethodError: private method `browser_name' called for {:browserName=>:firefox, :version=>nil}:Hash

here is the env.rb file :

```
   require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'

def browser_path
  (ENV['BPATH'])
end

def browser_name
  (ENV['BROWSER'] ||= 'firefox').downcase.to_sym
end

def environment
  (ENV['ENV'] ||= 'grid').downcase.to_sym
end

def browser_version
  (ENV['VER'])
end

Before do
  def assert_it message, &block
    begin
      if (block.call)
        puts "Assertion PASSED for #{message}"

      else
        puts "Assertion FAILED for #{message}"
        fail('Test Failure on assertion')
      end
    rescue => e
      puts "Assertion FAILED for #{message} with exception '#{e}'"
      fail('Test Failure on assertion')
    end
  end
  if browser_path != nil
    Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path= "#{browser_path}"
  end
  if environment == :grid
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url=>"http://10.196.60.38:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities=> {browserName: browser_name,version: browser_version})
    @browser.window.maximize
  else
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new browser_name
    @browser.window.maximize
  end

end

After do
  @browser.close
end
```

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`watir-webdriver` is deprecated and will not work with latest versions of Firefox. Please update to the latest version of `watir`.

Also with latest version of watir, you should be able to just do:

```
Watir::Browser.new(browser_name, url: "http://10.196.60.38:4444/wd/hub", version: browser_version
```

Comment: Thanks lot, that line is working now, but the first like of the senarion did not work :     Given(/^a user is at amazon$/) do
  @browser.goto "http://www.amazon.com"
end

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What is the error? Have you downloaded the geckodriver?

Comment: Please start a new question for that.  doing it here in the comments of another question is really cumbersome and sub-optimal.